# Generate all samples of given size with replacement in R

Tags: r, statistics, probability, distribution, sample

I want to generate all samples of size n = 2, with replacement, from the following data and then print the sampling distribution of sample means. I want to know that is there any standard R library for this?

This is what I have tried.

```
library(graphics)
data <- c(10, 12, 14, 16); n <- length(data)
mp <- vector(mode="numeric", length = 100)
for(i in data) {
  for(j in data) {
    mu <- mean(c(i, j))
    mp[mu] <- mp[mu] + 1
    tot <- tot + 1
    }
}
X_bar <- vector()
P_Xbar <- vector()
for(i in 1:length(mp)) {
  if(mp[i]) {
    X_bar <- c(X_bar, i)
    P_Xbar <- c(P_Xbar, mp[i] / tot)  
  }
}
tab <- data.frame(x <- X_bar, y <- P_Xbar); tab
barplot(tab$y * tot, names.arg=tab$x)
```

I think that I am doing lot of unnecessary stuff, can we do this using any standard R library ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get samples of size n with replacement

```
dataset = 1:100

sample(dataset, size = 2, rep=T)
```

To get means for N samples

```
N = 1000

means = replicate(N, mean(sample(dataset, 2, rep=T)))
```

To plot means

```
hist(means)
```

Ok, I see from your comment you want all possible n=2 permutations of the data. This can be achieved with:

```
library(gtools)
x = permutations(n=3, r=2, v=1:3, repeats.allowed=T)
# n = size of sampling vector 
# r = size of samples 
# v = vector to sample from
```

This gives you a matrix with each possible permutation including repeats:

```
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    1    1
 [2,]    1    2
 [3,]    1    3
 [4,]    2    1
 [5,]    2    2
 [6,]    2    3
 [7,]    3    1
 [8,]    3    2
 [9,]    3    3
```

To calculate means of this vector you can use:

```
rowMeans(x)
```

Comment: Thank you Adam for answering. But I want to select all the samples from this data: (10, 12, 14, 16) of size = 2. Thus, samples may look something like this: (10, 10), (10, 12), (10, 14), (10, 16), (12, 10), (12, 12), (12, 14), (12, 16), (14, 10), (14, 12), (14, 14), (14, 16), (16, 10), (16, 12), (16, 14), (16, 16).

Answer (score 1):

```
datax <- c(10, 12, 14, 16)
N <- length(datax) #size of sampling vector
n <- 2 #size of samples
x = permutations(n=N, r=n, v=datax, repeats.allowed=T)
# n = size of sampling vector 
# r = size of samples 
# v = vector to sample from
x
# include another column for the mean of each sample 
sdm <- cbind(x,rowSums(x)/n)
colnames(sdm) <- c(paste0("x",1:n), "mean")
sdm

#output
  x1 x2 mean
  [1,] 10 10   10
  [2,] 10 12   11
  [3,] 10 14   12
  [4,] 10 16   13
  [5,] 12 10   11
  [6,] 12 12   12
  [7,] 12 14   13
  [8,] 12 16   14
  [9,] 14 10   12
  [10,] 14 12   13
  [11,] 14 14   14
  [12,] 14 16   15
  [13,] 16 10   13
  [14,] 16 12   14
  [15,] 16 14   15
  [16,] 16 16   16
```